# elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
n1data = pcatrain_data[train_labels[0, :] == i, :]
n2data = pcatrain_data[train_labels[0, :] == j, :]
```

the shape of pcatrain_data is (14395,40)
and the shape of train_labels is (1,14395)

it is my understanding that "train_labels[0, :] == i" will return a list of boolean of size 14395 with values true where it is equal to i.

and since pcatrain_data is of size 14395 it shouldn't cause any errors.

this is the code that is causing the issue.
I am trying to get all the columns from specific rows of pcatrain_data. 
I want the rows where train_labels[0, :] == i.

I do not know why this error is coming, as I have done this before and it worked. both in python3

error is "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison"

Comment: Please don't add code as an image. Edit it into the body of the question

Answer (score -1):

you need to write

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

Then the warning can disapear

Comment: While this *does* remove the warnings, the root problem remains.